# loading UIView onto navigationalStack not passing strings across to new view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am trying to pass a string over to a detail view of my navigation controller
depending on the tableviewcell selected will depend on the value being passed.

for some reason the first cell thats selected passes the correct data across when i go back to the tableview and select the next cell (or any other cell including the first) it doesn't pass anything across...

here is my code.

MainView:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Sets the back button for the new view that loads (this overrides the usual parentview name with "Back")
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];

    if (!self.detailViewController) {
        self.detailViewController = [[ICDDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ICDDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            _detailViewController.parentViewSelectedIndexPath = @"one";
        }
        if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            _detailViewController.parentViewSelectedIndexPath = @"two";
        }
        if (indexPath.section == 2) {
            _detailViewController.parentViewSelectedIndexPath = @"three";
        }
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

then inside the detailed View

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    NSLog(@"%@", parentViewSelectedIndexPath);


}
```

This is the output, which shows I selected the first tableviewcell then everything after would not read.

```
2012-02-01 09:34:23.797 Diagram Test[1154:207] one
```

Comment: Why did you change from self.detailViewController to _detailViewController? I bet they are not the same thing! Change them all to self.detailViewController. There's really no good reason to use underscore in mainstream code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first class with the table, you have a line for if the detailView does not exist, to create it.

Chances are, the detailView is still loaded and retained by your tableView class.  If you want to reload the entire detailView based on what you touched in the table, take out the if(!detailView) line, and instead just run the self.detailView = [[yaddayadda alloc...

The -viewDidLoad method only fires once.

PS: you need to take the if (section ==) logic out of the if statement as well.

Change it to this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Sets the back button for the new view that loads (this overrides the usual parentview name with "Back")
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];


        self.detailViewController = [[ICDDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ICDDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            _detailViewController.parentViewSelectedIndexPath = @"one";
        }
        if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            _detailViewController.parentViewSelectedIndexPath = @"two";
        }
        if (indexPath.section == 2) {
            _detailViewController.parentViewSelectedIndexPath = @"three";
        }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess is beacuse... you are using viewDidLoad... you should use a method like this 
`-(void)setParentViewSelectedIndexPath:(NSString *)newParentViewSelectedIndexPath{
if (_parentViewSelectedIndexPath != newParentViewSelectedIndexPath) {
NSLog(@"%@", parentViewSelectedIndexPath);
}`

Comment: okay cool.. I was wondering if that was the issue but thought there might be another way around.. thanks for the conformation.

Comment: You should not use the results of NSLog to generate a string. If you must use [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", parentViewSelectedIndexpath]

Comment: i just paste the code from C.johns... inside the method i dont get it why the vote down?